# Background Image not visible when running in Java Swing using NetBeans IDE

Tags: java, image, swing, netbeans

I want to display the background image from the BackgroundFrame class to the MainFrame class. In the MainFrame class, I used this code to call the BackgroundFrame class and display the image at the center.

```
bg = new BackgroundFrame();
    add(bg, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

The rf and lf class should be placed on top of the bg (the bg is the background image for the project).

```
    lf = new LeftFrame();
    add(lf, BorderLayout.WEST);
    
    rf = new RightFrame();
    add(rf, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

In the BackgroundFrame class, I put the image in the NetBeans project so that I won't have to specify the file path; that's why I used "bg.png" as the path. **However, the background image is not visible when the program is running, what is wrong with my code?** I can't seem to figure it out, I'm still new at java.

**MainFrame.java**

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    
    LeftFrame lf;
    RightFrame rf;
    BackgroundFrame bg;
    
    public MainFrame() {
         
   
        lf = new LeftFrame();
        add(lf, BorderLayout.WEST);
        
        rf = new RightFrame();
        add(rf, BorderLayout.EAST);
        
        bg = new BackgroundFrame();
        add(bg, BorderLayout.CENTER);

//JFRAME SIZE
    setSize(5000,5000);
    setVisible(true);
    this.pack();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        

    }       
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainFrame();
    }
    
}
```

**BackgroundFrame.java**

```
public class BackgroundFrame extends JPanel {

ImageIcon img;
//DELETED THE SEONCD PANEL

public BackgroundFrame() {

img = new ImageIcon("bg.png");
JLabel bg = new JLabel(img);

//ADDED CODE JLABEL SIZE
bg.setSize(500, 500);

add(bg);

    
}
```

**RightFrame.java**

```
public class RightFrame extends JPanel {
    //no code yet
}
```

**LeftFrame.java**

```
public class LeftFrame extends JPanel {
    

    //this is used to describe the LeftFrame
public LeftFrame() {
    //my recent added codes
        
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.setSize(100, 100);
   
    }
```

Comment: Your `BackgroundFrame` is still only an empty `JPanel`, since you never add the `JLabel bg` with the image to it. So add a constructor for `BackgroundFrame` where you add `bg`.

Comment: Also, please do not repost your question, you just updated your [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73046489/background-image-to-show-in-the-main-class-using-jlabel) so there is no point in posting it again.

Comment: I edited the codes below and inserted a constructor at the BackgroundFrame.java. The output is just blank when I ran the program

Comment: You are missing the part where you actually **add** the `JLabel` to your `JPanel`. So do `add(bg)` aswell. But as already commented under your last question which you now deleted, please have a look at a [java swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) since you seem to lacking the very basics. Also, since you re-added the tag, your question is not specific to your IDE.

Comment: I added this.add(bg) but the output is blank. I tried implementing the bg.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER) but it's not working

Comment: Why would you call your class "BackgroundFrame" when you extend a "JPanel"? This is very confusing. Also, your class extends JPanel, so why are you creating a second panel? The suggestion was to use `add(bg)`. Post a proper [mre] showing what you have changed. Stating you made a change in a comment doesn't show us where you actually made the change. How do you know you actually read the image? Did you display the preferred size of the label? Use ImageIO to read the image. You will get an error message if the image is not found. Forget about the left/right panels. Get  one panel working first.

Comment: @camickr for calrification, instead of using ImageIcon, I need to used Image IO? ex. "BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File(src));". Here's my reference 
-> https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/javax.imageio.ImageIO/read

Comment: Yes, and then you use the Image to create the ImageIcon to be used by the JLabel.

Comment: @camickr I added a code at the LeftFrame.java, and I just want to check if it's okay if I didn't add a Layout manager at the LeftFrame class since there is a BorderLayout.West at the MainFrame.java (JFrame) that aims to put the LeftFrame at the West side of the Frame. 
Instead of using a Layout manager, I just set the bg color and the size of the LeftFrame JPanel. My goal is to add another Jpanel (LeftFrame.java) on top of the bg image BackgroundFrame.java. Thank you for the patience.


this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.setSize(100, 100);

Comment: Your question is about adding an image to a panel. Your left pane is irrelevant to your stated question. Keep a posting to a single question otherwise it gets too confusing trying to answer multiple questions. By the way a JPanel uses a FlowLayout by default and the setSize() will do nothing. The layout manager will set the size/location of the component based on the preferred sizes of the components added to the panel.